# Mid-century novel read in elementary school, about a woman with coloured skin and her guardian on a distant planet

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, science, female-characters

Any help with this would be much appreciated, as it's been slowly driving me insane.

In elementary school (c. mid 90s), the entire class read a sci-fi novel about a girl with coloured-skin (green or blue maybe ?) essentially deserted on a (dusty/not an abundance of life ?) planet (in a different system) with her guardian (I don't think it was the same species, may have been AI), and she performs scientific observations and research, and something major obviously happens in the book (I think at one point she is separated from her guardian) for the sake of plot development.

I feel like I may have not finished reading it, so my apologies for not being more help.

Comment: Could be _The Keeper of the Isis Light_ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light

Comment: Definitely is - I literally JUST tracked it down, but thank you for the confirmation! (yay, I'm not crazy!)

Comment: You should write up the answer & accept it (in a couple days) so it's marked solved.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a dupe, but please don't feel that that's a censure of any sort. It's just how we do bookkeeping around here.

Comment: Self-answers have to wait 48 hours from asking before they can be accepted, but as per the [tour], then you can click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept it.

Comment: Thank you FuzzyBoots and eshier.
First time on the site, so thank you for your guidance - I will check off the answer in a couple days time ;)

Answer (score 6):

*[The Keeper of the Isis Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light)*, by Monica Hughes!

> Olwen is a young human woman living on the planet Isis as the keeper of the Light (a navigation beacon). Her parents having died, her only companion is a robotic DaCoP (Data Collector and Processor), called Guardian. On Olwen's 16th birthday (10th on Isis), the Guardian tells her that settlers are coming from Earth to Cascade Valley. Olwen is in distress thinking that these settlers will ruin her perfect world.

....

> Later, Guardian tells Olwen the truth about the death of her parents, and his subsequent care of her as her mother wished. To keep Olwen safe, he changed her genetically, so the ultraviolet rays from Isis' sun, Ra, would not harm her, allowing her to climb to Isis' mountain heights. Shocked at the realization that Mark fell because of her, Olwen tries to enjoy playing with her favourite pet, a dragon-like native animal called Hobbit, when Hobbit is shot by hunting settlers. In rage, Olwen chases the Hunters back to the village. When the settlers see Olwen, they are disgusted by her appearance. Olwen refuses to wear the suit and vows to never go down into Cascade Valley again.